# Can I have single tablespace excluded from DataGuard

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, dataguard

Can I have single tablespace not being logged and excluded from DataGuard with in same database?  We are trying to keep objects owned by a schema isolated in one tablespace and set those objects for `NOLOGGING`, hence not using DataGuard (only for that one tablespace).

I am not an Oracle expert but from other RDBMS  knowledge this is not possible (with exception of Read_only filegroup).  I would prefer a yes/no answer if there is one.

I am being told:

> I am pretty sure that a tablespace can be excluded from logging when
> using Data Guard.  Then we just need to keep the two tablespaces apart
> physically in the filesystem.

I am not worried about if I can recover or no (I will have that discussion with the requester once I sort out my first question). I need to know if single tablespace can be excluded from DataGuard or it is a database level setting and not possible.